# Cypress Not Allowing Configurable Tests

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I would like Cypress to auto-generate an it block for each item in the below hash. When I currently run cypress, it picks up on the second test just fine, but ignores the one with the while loop. How can I resolve this? I'd prefer not to have to write out an explicit it block for each item in the map.

```
   const testDataMappings = { 
        1: {e2eTestName: 'test-one'},
        2: {e2eTestName: 'test-two'},
        3: {e2eTestName: 'test-three'},
    }
    
// Does not work
    describe('My Tests', function () {
        let i = 1;
        while (i < testDataMappings.length + 1) {
            let entry = testDataMappings[i];
            it("Should Do The Thing Correctly For" + entry.e2eTestName, () => {
                const standardCaseUrl = Cypress.config().baseUrl + "?profile_id=" + String(i);
                cy.visit(standardCaseUrl);
                cy.wait(5000);
                cy.get('.some-div-class-name').compareSnapshot(entry.e2eTestName, 0.0);
            });
            i +=1;
        }

// works
        describe('Another Describe block', function () {
            it('Should do the thing', () => {
                const standardCaseUrl = Cypress.config().baseUrl + "?profile_id=1";
                cy.visit(standardCaseUrl);
                cy.wait(5000); 
                cy.get('.some-div-class-name').compareSnapshot('some-snapshot-name', 0.0);
            });
        });
    });
```

Console logs don't seem to show up, so don't have much insight into what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app).  The example is in the [transaction feeds spec](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/tests/ui/transaction-feeds.spec.ts#L169) and uses `lodash` `each` to iterate over a `feedViews` object and dynamically generate the tests for each feed.